# Know if a MovieClip will trigger a function

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Ok, so I have this movie clip X and I need to check if it has a listener to a function... I know about the hasListener thing, but I can only send an event type to it right? Like MouseEvent.CLICK, or anything like that.

What I need to know is if I can get an exact function that will trigger when the event is dispatched. willTrigger() can help me with something?

Comment: Why do you want to check if it has a listener to a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NO, you can't get the function object which will be called for a particular event. `willTrigger` won't help either. If you need the listener function later then you need to remember that yourself.

The best way to remember listener functions will depend on your particular need. One possible way is to extend the `MovieClip` and override `addEventListener` to save the listeners in an object. You can use the event type as the key and an array of listeners(every event type can have more than one listeners) as value.

Answer (score 0):

`willTrigger()` will just work it's way through the event bubbling.  You could always extend the event you're looking to use to make it a custom event that you could check against to know for sure.